# Monitor broken or changed settings? Blues have lines and whites with yellow tint

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, display, laptop-repair

Very recently, my Lenovo y510p laptop's monitor has been having display problems with blues and whites. In my setup I also have a second monitor connected to the laptop. The second monitor has no display issues. My graphics cards include an Intel HD Graphics 4600 and an NVIDIA GT750M.

Using this [photo](https://cbpofarizonainc.com/wp-content/uploads/double-contrast-decor-dark-blue-walls-light-yellow-furniture.jpg) as an example, this is what the screen currently looks like [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flgxO.jpg). Changing contrast settings in the Intel Graphics sort of removes the yellowish tint to white areas in the screen but nothing is perfect.

Could the display have been damaged or could something have come loose? I travel with my laptop in a backpack at least 4 days of the week. Is this a hardware issue (display rather than graphics card)?

Adding something new, after some period of time later without changing, moving or doing anything to the laptop the display suddenly goes back to normal.

Comment: Have you looked at the resolution and the color settings?  It should be set to the highest resolution and 32 bit color (for most modern laptops).  If there was a hardware issue, there would probably be black sections that don't get any color info or vertical lines through the whole monitor.  However a broken wire in the cable from the card to your LCD could be messing with the laptop recognizing the monitor correctly, causing it to change resolution and color settings on you.

Comment: It does look kind of like a low colour mode. If it's a ribbon cable, they might be very easy to change, it's just getting the laptop apart to reach them could  be a challenge

Comment: Looking at the Intel Graphics Control Panel, yes it is set to 32 bit color and to the highest resolution possible, 1920x1080. At the moment everything looks good and I have no idea what triggers it. Earlier today it had the effect from the picture above for the first time and then suddenly went back to normal when I was doing nothing to fix it. When I brought the laptop back home, sometime before this post, it started up with the effect and only a few minutes ago went back to normal.

Comment: I am believing it may have been a software issue or something was corrupted. Around the time of this started other minor things were acting up such as VirtualBox VMs giving errors and warnings that Windows Security Center were turned off. I decided to start new and did a 'remove everything' Windows reinstall and things seem to be back to normal.